# How to compare dates for deadline in Angular and CSS?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new into Angular 8 and just learned timestamp to string conversion using interpolation and .toMillis, however I want to improve this one on my project app.

i'm trying to compare the saved date from my firestore to the current date today for deadline display.

if the date is not not less than a day from the deadline my data place holder background should be green

if the date is 1 day less from the or the deadline my data place holder background should be orange

if the date is past the deadline my data place holder background should be red.

Comment: Hi @CarloA. Is this really a CSS question?

Comment: Take a look at [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Answer (score 1):

I have written a sample [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7k1sq), guideing how to use pipe to change `background-color`

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateCss'
})
export class DateCssPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any { // write you comparator here
    if(new Date(value) > new Date()){
      return 'bg-red';
    }
    else {
      return 'bg-orange';
    }
  }
}
```

`dateCss` is the name of pipe
`xyzDate` and `xyzDate2` are variables

```html
<div class="{{ xyzDate | dateCss }}">XYZ {{xyzDate | date: 'medium'}}<div>
<div class="{{ xyzDate2 | dateCss }}">XYZ2 {{xyzDate2 | date: 'medium'}}
```

[Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) on writing pipes